# Add all review types to user_timeline in Stack Exchange API

Tags: feature-request, api

In the Stack Exchange API, for a user's past actions (analogous to the 'All Actions' section of a user profile), there's [user_timeline](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user-timeline).  However, it contains very limited information on the review history for the user, it only contains their reviews of Suggested Edits.

I request that this be fleshed out to include all the types of reviews.  Information anyone can view under a user's All Actions should all be in the API.